# How to recreated users' home folders?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2019

Users already have their home folders set through Active Directory to mount as U: drive to `\\SRV\Usrs$\%UserName%`

I had to create the folder again and share the `$Usrs` again but when a user logs into the workstation the new home folder is not created in that folder.
Is there a way to force creation of those folder without setting the home folder again for all users? (I have the access to Storage server but don't have access to AD or control over user accounts)

Comment: Check your NTFS and Share permissions on newly created folder \\SRV\Usrs$

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko I tried giving full control to SYSTEM, CREATOR OWNER, Domain Users, Local\Administrators